# Unable to scroll from tabbed pages in ios

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin, scrollview

I have created four tabs

1. Current
2. Upcoming
3. Archived
4. Cancelled

Each page contains a listview.

Onclick of 1.current is able to scroll list but onclick of other tabs are not able to scroll

Expecting to scroll list onclick of each bottom tab in ios

I tried scrollTO method

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class TrainBookingPage : TabbedPage
{
    public TrainBookingPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var navCurrentBooking = new NavigationPage(new CurrentTrainBooking());
        navCurrentBooking.Title = "  Current";

        var navUpcomingBooking = new NavigationPage(new UpcomingTrainBooking());
        navUpcomingBooking.Title = "Upcoming";

        var navArchivedBooking = new NavigationPage(new ArchivedTrainBooking());
        navArchievedBooking.Title = "Archived";

        var navCancelledBooking = new NavigationPage(new CancelledTrainBooking());
        navCancelledBooking.Title = "Cancelled";

        Children.Add(navCurrentBooking);
        Children.Add(navUpcomingBooking);
        Children.Add(navArchivedBooking);
        Children.Add(navCancelledBooking);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. Could you please add more details and code examples?

Comment: Can you share the code in `UpcommingTrainBooking()` which is not able to scroll?